# Want to create user defined aggregate function in postgresql

Tags: aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.4

I want to create an aggregate function which will return same value which is passed to it mostly int or bigint type of value.

The purpose for doing this is that when I try to group by it is asking me to put value in the aggregate function as one value is already in a **group by** which I want I don't want to put another one in it.

Postgres version 9.4

Have below query to execute to get a proper result :

```
select org_id,
case when add_pos_or_zero(status_id)=4 then count(id) else 0 end as closed,
case when add_pos_or_zero(status_id)!=4 then count(id) else 0 end as open ,
case when add_pos_or_zero(status_id) in (1,2,4,5) then count(id) else 0 end as created
from cloudschema.ticket_mstr  where 
to_char(to_timestamp(created_on/1000),'dd/MM/yyyy')='23/08/2017' and is_active is true group BY org_id;
```

Please see fiddle : [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dc827/4)

I want result in this form:

```
orgid closed open created
 891     1    2    3
 912     0    1    1
 918     0    1    1
```

Comment: This sounds as if you just need a different solution than `group by`. It would be better to show us the your **real** problem

Comment: I haven't received any answer.Please help.